# Facebook sharer.php AngularJS Prerender IO issue

Tags: facebook, angularjs, url, share, prerender

This is an issue with sharing an url from an AngularJS / Prerender.io app.
I wonder if that is maybe due to the reason that the url is too long?

I am creating the share so it looks like this:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowness.airnauts.com%2Fseries%2Fin-residence-architecture-design-video-series%2Fin-residence-ricardo-bofill-nowness

that one link is not working. Facebook's parser doesn't get the page title, og:title etc.

All Other links work correctly, examples:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowness.airnauts.com%2Fseries%2Fin-residence-architecture-design-video-series
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowness.airnauts.com%2Fseries

and even this one, which leads to the same content:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowness.airnauts.com%2Fstory%2Fin-residence-ricardo-bofill-nowness

The page is rendered correctly by prerender.io:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/prerender/2361/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nowness.airnauts.com%2Fseries%2Fin-residence-architecture-design-video-series%2Fin-residence-ricardo-bofill-nowness

The issue is also described on facebook bugs https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1478457142420355/

Comment: Is this the correct URL? http://www.nowness.airnauts.com/series/in-residence-architecture-design-video-series/in-residence-ricardo-bofill-nowness. It redirects me to a 404 page.

Comment: the series name changed, now it is http://www.nowness.airnauts.com/series/in-residence/ricardo-bofills-house-by-albert-moya

I temporarily resolved the issue by pointing the sharer url to another url, where the video is accessible (listed above)